# Parsing Webservice data iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, web-services, nsxmlparser

Good Afternoon all ,

I have downloaded data from a web service and im looking to parse that data so that i can use it , but I'm having problems parsing the returned values , below is the aquisition code and anything else in between ANY help would be appreciated

```
 -(IBAction)runNewImport:(id)sender{


recordResults = FALSE;

soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:

               @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"

               "<s:Envelope \n"

               "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
               "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n" 
               "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
               "s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
               "xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"       


               "<s:Body> \n"

               "<[FUNCTION] xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"/>\n"

               "</s:Body> \n"
               "</s:Envelope>"];


[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://[PATH]"];      
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];             
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];          
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];       
[theRequest addValue: @"[FUNCTION]" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];     
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(theConnection) {
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"%@",webData);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}       



}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"THIS IS THE DATA : %@",theXML);


xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
[xmlParser setDelegate:self];
[xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
[xmlParser parse];


}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)
 elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) 
 namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
  attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"CODE"])
{
    soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@",soapResults);
    recordResults = TRUE;
}
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)
 elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

{
if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"CODE"])
{
    recordResults = FALSE;
    soapResults = nil;
    }
}
```

Thanks for looking and again , all help is welcome

Comment: You forgot to mention what problems you encounter when parsing.

Comment: Also, your `soapResults` return from the `NSLog` is probably blank huh?

Comment: yep , its not even showing up . The problem is that its NOT parsing and ive been trying to figure it out for a while now , the XML is there and available , below find a sample of the XML file

Comment: <a:ECRMPERSONNEL><a:SYSREF>36</a:SYSREF><a:CODE>TEST</a:CODE><a:FULLNAME>TEST</a:FULLNAME><a:ADDRESS1/><a:ADDRESS2/><a:ADDRESS3/><a:ADDRESS4/><a:TELEPHONEWORK/><a:TELEPHONEHOME/><a:MOBILEWORK/><a:MOBILEOTHER/><a:EMAILWORK>TEST</a:EMAILWORK><a:CC1/><a:CC2/><a:CC3/><a:STATUS>A</a:STATUS><a:TYPE>M</a:TYPE><a:IFOTHER>N/A</a:IFOTHER><a:COSTPERHOUR>0.00</a:COSTPERHOUR><a:CHARGERATEPERHOUR>0.00</a:CHARGERATEPERHOUR></a:ECRMPERSONNEL><a:ECRMPERSONNEL>

Comment: It's not showing up because you allocate and initialize it then you NSLog it.  You never assign any value to it, you just NSLog the blank string that you created.

Comment: so how would you do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the way NSXMLParser works. I urge you to take a good look at this doc from Apple [XML parsing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI)

```
-(void)parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:
```

this method is called when the parser finds an opening XML tag like , so it doesn't have any data on it yet. Here, you only need to alloc memory for whatever you want to save

```
- (void)parser:foundCharacters:
```

is called when there is data inside a tag which was found in `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` this is where you store that data first so that you can later save it on the object you want in the next method:

```
-(void)parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName
```

is called when the parser encounters a closing tag (). Now you have the data you kept in a variable in `parser:foundCharacters:` and it's time to save it in your object.

**EDIT:** Alright, lets try and break it down by adding code samples in these methods:

Let's say you have an XML looking like this;

```
<person>
    <lastName>Doe</lastName>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <address>
        <street>100 Main Street</street>
        <city>Somewhere</city>
    </address>
</person>
```

Naturally, you'd want to have a `Person` class with the properties *lastName*, *firstName* and *addressDictionary* containing *street* and *city*. And to keep all the `Person`s, you'd need *personArray*.

Now we have the structure, here is the parsing part. 
Please do note that for the sake of better understanding, I'll be writing each *If* block separately.

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Person *currentPerson;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *currentElement;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *addressDic; //to be saved to person.addressDictionary when finished
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *personArray;
```

.m file

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{
    personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement: (NSString *) elementName
 namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *) qName attributes: (NSDictionary *) attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Person"])
    {
    currentPerson = [[Person alloc] init]; //
    return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastName"])
    {
        currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstName"])
    {
        currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        adressDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"street"])
    {
        currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"city"])
    {
        currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        return;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentElement appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Person"])
    {
    [personArray addObject:currentPerson];
    [currentPerson release];
    return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"lastName"])
    {
        currentPerson.lastName = currentElement;
        [currentElement release]; currentElement = nil;
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstName"])
    {
        currentPerson.firstName = currentElement;
        [currentElement release]; currentElement = nil;
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        currentPerson.addressDictionary = addresDic;
        [addressDic release];
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"street"])
    {
        [addressDic setObject:currentElement forKey:@"street"];
        [currentElement release]; currentElement = nil;
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"city"])
    {
        [addressDic setObject:currentElement forKey:@"city"];
        [currentElement release]; currentElement = nil;
        return;
    }
}
```

When this is all done, `parserDidEndDocument:` gets called. Now that you have all the `Person`s in your array, do whatever you like with them

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
     for (Person *person in personArray)
     {
          NSLog(@"Person name:%@", person.firstName);
          NSLog(@"Person lastname:%@", person.lastName);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but how would you change it ? im asking because i have experience with XML Parsing because ive already done something before but i cant get this to work

Comment: What do you mean by changing it?

Comment: That was absolutely brilliant , I've never had someone try to help me so much , but alas , this being the real world , its still not working , i have a feeling its something to do with the format of the xml that I'm receiving , i posted a sample up top to try and get the others to understand , i have a feeling this is going to be a loooooong night :/ Thumbs up for the brilliant answer

Comment: Appreciate your words of praise. Since the sole purpose of helping is not yet achieved, I'll stick around to find a solution. First off, does it nor work when you write `isEqualToString:@"a:ECRMPERSONNEL"`, try to NSLog only the `elementName` in `parser:didStartElement:...` and tell me what the log says

Comment: i tried NSLog on the Element Name and it doesnt even come up in the debugger console,

Comment: NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
 NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
 [parser setDelegate:self];
 [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
 [parser parse];

Comment: keep in mind that webData variable is an NSMutableData Variable

Comment: If it doesn't show in the console then `parser:didStartElement..` is not called. First, just to make sure, you see the XML log coming from `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` right? If so, also make sure you added `<NSXMLParserDelegate>` in your .h file and go with `[parser setDelegate:self];[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];[parser parse];`

Comment: i took a look at all of those , its as if the NSMUtableDataVariable containing all of the xml data doesnt even want to be read by the parser

Comment: Could you please post ALL the logs you see on the console? For all we know, your problem may even be with NSURLConnection. You're not being very specific at the moment and to avoid extended comments as StackOverflow states, you need to be specific by giving more info :)

Comment: just finished from work , and im really and truly annoyed , my database administrator is too stupid to remove nulls from the database , so when the xml was being passed , it was crashing the program , i know this because when i checked the xml with a validator , it pointed at the null records ... Thanks for all the help